# What does eigenvalues represent in Face Recognition by Eigenfaces

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I've got a set of training face images (40 images). Each image size is 28*34. From there, I'm able to get eigenVector, Score, Latent using `princomp` function in Matlab.

I've got 952 latents (eigenvalues in covariance matrix) which are in descending form : 4.2785 to 0 . Eigenvalues are zeros from k=40 onwards.

May i know what does the the eigenvalues indicate ? (say bigger value means more significant to variance?)  how could I identify the best k value (Principal component)?

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 40 input faces you cannot expect to have more than 40 principal components. Therefore the eigenvalue becomes zero for K=40 onwards.
To visualize your results, take the 40 leading eigen vectors, `reshape` them back to 28-by-34 and `imagesc` them. What have you got?

Comment: Hi, I got 952 x 952 dimension in eigenvectors, may i know how to reshape back them ?

Comment: @user3168226 take the first column and reshape it to `28`-by-`34` matrix. then take the second and so on...

Answer (score 0):

- EigenValue of an eigenvector represents how important you eigenvector is.
- Higher the Eigenvalue  more important the eigentvector is
- for 40 images the eigenvectors can not be more than 40
- You can reconstruct the faces with the eigencvectors to visualize how it looks like
- The eigenvector with highest eigenvalue is a principal component where most of the data lies

  - You can refer this link https://github.com/jayshah19949596/Computer-Vision/blob/master/EigenFaces/EigenFaces.ipynb ... This is a nice tutorial on EigenFaces